# ASM subroutine to print coloured text at specific location on the screen

Tags: assembly, nasm, bootloader, bios

I'm trying to write some ASM code that will write some text to the display using BIOS interrupts. This code will run from the boot sector.

I have

```asm
msgText DB "Hello"                  ;Text
msgCol  DB 0x07,0x08,0x09,0x0A,0x0B ;Colours
msgXY   DW 0x0E26                   ;Col/Row
msgLen  DB 0x05                     ;Length
```

The message is just "Hello", each letter having a different colour. The position of the message on the screen is roughly in the middle, and it has a length of 5.

I want to write a function that will write *any* message/colour/xy/length to the screen, but for now, let's focus on this one.

```asm
print:
  MOV AH,0x02        ;Tell BIOS we want to set the cursor position
  MOV DX,[msgXY]     ;Tell BIOS where the cursor should go
  INT 0x10           ;Call BIOS video interrupt

  XOR ECX,ECX        ;Clear ECX
  MOV CX,[msgLen]    ;Set CX = msgLen

  MOV AH,0x0E        ;We want to print characters on the screen

  _loop:
    MOV EDX,msgText  ;Move address of text to EDX
    DEC ECX          ;Temporarily decrement ECX
    ADD EDX,ECX      ;Add ECX to the address of msgText
    INC ECX          ;Increment ECX back to what it was
    MOV AL,BYTE[EDX] ;Put the contents of the memory at EDX into AL

    MOV EDX,msgCol   ;Move address of text colour to EDX
    DEC ECX          ;Temporarily decrement ECX
    ADD EDX,ECX      ;Add ECX to the address of msgCol
    INC ECX          ;Increment ECX back to what it was
    MOV BL,BYTE[EDX] ;Put the contents of the memory at EDX into BL

    INT 0x10         ;Call BIOS video interrupt
    LOOP _loop
  RET
```

Now, I should be able to call this with `CALL print`.

(yes, I know this prints "Hello" backwards, I'm not worried about that. I can just store it in memory as "olleH", I don't care - I've got much bigger problems)

First of all, the line where I set `CX` to `[msgLen]` causes problems. I've had to hardcode it to make `CX` equal to `0x05` and I'm not sure why.

Secondly, presumably for the same reason, when I try to set the colour code I have the same problem as the text length. If I get rid of those lines and just hardcode `MOV BL,0x0C`, then it works fine.

Oddly, however, the `MOV DX,[msgXY]` part seems to work OK.

I can't give any exact problems, because I've been trying to fix this for hours by changing lots of thing, and little things I change here and there seem to have very unpredictable results. Furthermore, calling various BIOS interrupts seems to *change* some of the registers, which is very annoying. Also, when I push stuff down onto the stack and pop it back out later, it's different, so I've been avoiding `PUSH` and `POP` altogether.

By the way, I'm still in real mode x86 at this stage.

Surely what I'm doing can't be this hard. Maybe I just need a coffee. Or some help? :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, "first of all", you've defined `msgLen` as `db`. When you `mov cx, [msgLen]`, you load two bytes. Whether this causes a problem depends on what (if anything) is after `msgLen`. Either define `msgLen` as `dw`, or do `mov cl, [msgLen]` (since you've got the upper bits cleared).

I don't see a similar problem with "Secondly" - you're moving a byte into an 8-bit register. Seems strange that you're using 32-bit registers in this section. "Should" work, but it bloats up your code a bit. `[dx]` is not a valid 16-bit addressing mode, of course - you'd have to use `bx` (which is being used for other purposes), `si`, or `di`. Since you are using 32-bit registers, `lea edx, [edx + ecx - 1]` should do what you want without temporarily decrementing and incrementing `ecx`. (but I don't think that'll help your problem)

It is expected that certain BIOS interrupts would alter registers. Whether it's weird or not depends on which interrupts are doing it. Mostly they don't. Not being able to `pop` the same value you `push`ed is weird. Either you've discovered a CPU bug or you're doing something wrong. Guess which is more likely. :) They're useful instructions, so it's a shame not to be able to use 'em. You don't show "act I" of your bootsector, where you initialize `ds` and `es` and set up a sensible stack - perhaps there's a problem there?

Have you looked at int 10h/13h? I think it'll do what you want ("rainbow" text). It's a weird interrupt, in that it expects the text address to be in `es:bp`, but useful. Another approach is to poke character and color directly to "screen memory" at B800h:xxxx - one byte for character and one byte for color.

A bootsector isn't particularly easy to write. If you've got real dos available (or even Dosbox), it may help to "try out" your routines as part of a .com file (where DEBUG is available). A bootsector is a different environment from dos, so it won't solve all your problems, but may help to narrow it down.

Coffee may help, but mostly... Courage!

Best,
Frank

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. So far, I haven't got much else in "act 1". The first stage boot loader on sector 0 does nothing but read the following sector and far jump to it. The code you see here is what's there (minus a few bits). Just after this bit, I enable A20 and protected mode, but I haven't even given thought to stack or GDT yet - still very complicated for me.

Comment: So... ds=?, es=?, ss=?, sp=? Wherever the BIOS leaves 'em? This may work on one particular machine, but isn't likely to work on "any machine". Maybe this isn't necessary for your purposes. I wouldn't be in too much of a rush to get into Pmode. At least find out how much memory you've got installed while you've still got BIOS interrupts available. http://www.osdev.org has probably been mentioned enough times, but it won't hurt to mention it again - loads of good information there! Happy bootin'!

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use This Code:

```
mov si,msg_text
call print_colored
print_colored:
.loop:
lodsb
cmp al,0
je .done
inc bl
mov ah,0x0E
Int 0x10
jmp .loop
.done:
ret
```

It makes your String colored but not for your choice.